# How to PARTITION a table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database-design, innodb, partitioning

I read a lot of articles that `PARTITION`ing is not helpful in most cases. I believe it should speed up the queries in my case. I have a table with the structure of

```
CREATE TABLE pages
(
page_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
category_id smallint(5) unsigned,
title varchar(255),
created datetime,
updated datetime,
FOREIGN KEY(category_id) REFERENCES categories(category_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
UNIQUE INDEX (category_id,title),
INDEX(title),
PRIMARY KEY(page_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED
```

The table is close to 1 billion rows and 200-1000 `category_id`.

Almost all queries have `category_id` in it.

I consider `PARTITION`ing the table as

```
PARTITION BY KEY(category_id)
PARTITIONS 40; // between 20-50
```

Is it worthy?

Comment: Why don't you ask about your slow queries? After all, those are the things you want to be faster and you've read PARITIIONING is rarely helpful (and pretty impossible to determine without knowing your queries).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have bad news with regard to this table: MySQL does not support Partitioning of a Table with Foreign Keys

According to [MySQL 5.7 Docs on Partitioning Limitations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-limitations-storage-engines.html)

> **InnoDB storage engine.**  InnoDB foreign keys and MySQL partitioning are not compatible. ***Partitioned InnoDB tables cannot have foreign key references, nor can they have columns referenced by foreign keys. InnoDB tables which have or which are referenced by foreign keys cannot be partitioned***.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough information.  What are the queries against the table -- in more detail.

Meanwhile, ...

What do you mean by "Almost all queries have category_id"?  It makes a big difference as to whether you are doing

```
WHERE category_id = constant
```

versus

```
WHERE category_id IN (...)
```

For the former case, I would push for having `category_id` as the first column in the `PRIMARY KEY`:

```
PRIMARY KEY(category_id, title)   -- helps with queries, and is UNIQUE
INDEX(page_id)   -- to keep auto_inc happy
```

On the other hand, is that all the columns in the table??  If, that's all, I am having trouble imagining more than a couple of different `SELECTs`, namely mapping cat+title to page_id and vice versa.  If that is all, then what you have is optimal.  And what I have is equally optimal, with the slight improvement of having one fewer `UNIQUE` constraint.

If you have `category_id IN (...)` then (again) we need to see the rest of the `WHERE`.

Answer (score 0):

You will get a error if you try partitioning by category_id because primary key needs to be in partition column. So the short answer is no.

Very large tables become problematic typically because you want to delete data (which partitions on time series tables) or because of slow queries, so share a query with us and let's see if we can fix it.